# Static Initialization order fiasco: how can we ensure that library X would get linked only once Protobuf is done?

Tags: linker-errors, static-order-fiasco

We have 2 libraries - Google Protobuf (version 4.2) and a library 'X'..
a particular object of X when initialized uses certain functions of protobuf, thus resulting in a crash of our application, as library X is getting linked first followed by Protobuf..
How can we ensure that library X would get linked only once Protobuf is done?
Do we have some linker option/flag to do the same?

Comment: Also see [AddressSanitizerInitializationOrderFiasco](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerInitializationOrderFiasco).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, initialization order of different compilation units has undefined behavior.
I often rely on a Singleton or a Factory to impose a proper initialization order.